# Ramsey number for tree and complete graph

Tags: combinatorics, ramsey-theory

I am having a lot of trouble understanding Ramsey theory.  I am working on an exercise that asks for the Ramsey number $R(T,K_{1,n+1})$ where $T$ is a tree with $m$ edges and $n$ is a multiple of $m$.

I am not sure what exactly the Ramsey number for this means or how to begin finding it.  I understand that usually problems like these involve finding lower and upper bounds.

In the linked problem, 
I am not understanding how the following claim is made:

Suppose you have the graph $G=(\frac{n−1}{m−1}+1)×K_{m−1}$,
Then $T_m$ is not in $G$, and $K_{1,n}$ is not in $\bar{G}$. I am also looking for some help with the logic for finding the upper bound.  I am trying to use the observation that you can pick the root of the tree or the single node in the bipartite graph but from there I can't see a construction for the desired objects.

Comment: Fixed it, should have been $n$ is a multiple of $m$.

Comment: The Ramsey number $R(T,K_{1,n+1})$ is the minimum $p\in\mathbb{N}$ such that any two coloring of the complete graph $K_p$ contains either a subgraph isomorphic to $T$ all of the first color or a subgraph isomorphic to $K_{1,n+1}$ isomorphic to the second color. This question has already been asked here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1350265/calulating-the-ramsey-number-rt-k-1-n-of-a-tree-t-and-bipartite-graph